# Visual studio Web Performance tests - OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing, identityserver3, web-testing

I am trying to create the Web Performance tests for an app that is using Identity Server 3. I can't figure out how to simulate login and get token.

For example, I am using `myapp.com` and identity server is hosted on `identity.com`. All my endpoints in `myapp.com/api` are secured and require Bearer token. 
`identity.com` can provide me token in exchange for a username and password. `identity.com` will redirect me to a `myapp.com/tokenRedirect?token=***`. How can I catch the token and use it as an Authorization header for API requests?

There are some solutions for JMeter but could not find any for VS 2017 tests.

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to make it clearer. If it has been answered then please read about [accepting answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Redirections are handled automatically, by default, in a test recorded by Visual Studio and hence the redirection response containing the token is not accessible. Setting the `FollowRedirects` property of the request to `False` allows the response containing the redirection to be accessed by the usual extraction rules and/or plugins etc. One of them can be used to find the token value and save it to a context parameter (CP). Having turned off the automatic redirection handling, a new request should be added (use the `Insert request` command, do not use `Add dependent request`) and it should have the request that the redirection wants. Hence its url should be of the form `myapp.com/tokenRedirect?token={{TheCPWithTheToken}}`.

In later requests the CP with the token can be added via the `Add header` command, or an existing header field can be modified to use the CP.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianHHH, works for me (had a similar question too).